# Can you say '' I just got home from a football match''?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

So basically, I want to say '' I was really tired because I just got home from a football match'', then on second thought, I think it might be better to replace the word '' from'' with '' after''.
Please help me to clear up this doubt!

Comment: _Get home from [somewhere]_ is fine, but you could use _after_ if you wished.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! @KateBunting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both *from* and *after* work in this situation. There's certainly been [a bit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/2z2vri/since_vs_after_what_is_the_linguistic_difference/) [of discussion](https://wikidiff.com/content/vs-after-whats-difference-0) [about this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/from-vs-after.2405336/), but I think [this is a good article](https://e-gmat.com/blogs/since-vs-from/) that should more fully explain.

Comment: Thank you so much @Eliot K!! It was really helpful!